# Error in creating training and test vectors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to recreate the code to train iris dataset given in link-
https://tf-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/tflearn/

However I get a valueerror when I try to run the following part of the code:

```
# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
```

Error is:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sepal length'

Can someone help troubleshoot this?

Comment: Somewhere your program expects an int but gets the string 'Sepal length'. You should check where the string 'Sepal length' occurs in your input file.

Comment: did you download the csv files from the tutorial?

Comment: "Sepal length" does occur in the header of the csv file and it is the first heading. So my guess is all the header values are a problem. Is there a way to avoid reading the header of the csv file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('iris_training.csv')
dataset = df.values
```

Then use `from_tensor_slices` instead

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
```

The simple solution which does not involve any coding is just manually remove the header using a text editor, then push through with your approach right now.